# Company mode won't autocomplete variables with underscores

Tags: company-mode, company

I have web-mode and company installed but company just seems to autocomplete the variables without underscores:

With Emacs Lisp Mode

[image]

With Web-mode
[image]

```
;; --- Company ---
;; Autocomplete with dropdown system

(use-package company
  :ensure t
  
  :init
  
  :config
  (setq company-dabbrev-ignore-case t)
  (setq company-dabbrev-downcase nil)
  
  (setq company-idle-delay 0.2)
  (setq company-echo-delay 0)
  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)
  (setq company-tooltip-minimum-width 110)

  (setq company-dabbrev-code-everywhere t)
  (setq company-dabbrev-code-modes t)
  (setq company-tooltip-align-annotations t)
  (setq company-selection-wrap-around t)

  (setq company-transformers '(company-sort-by-occurrence
                           company-sort-by-backend-importance))

  ;; (define-key global-map (kbd "C-.") 'company-files)
  
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)

  (setq company-backends
        '((company-files
           company-yasnippet
           company-dabbrev
           company-keywords
           company-capf
           company-php
           )))

  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setting of `company-backends`, don't use `company-dabbrev` in that group, use `company-dabbrev-code`.

Comment: I marked this one as the proper answer, my own works as well, but this one is far cleaner and less intrusive than changing the syntax of Emacs. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem is not a company problem but the syntax of the mode. By default Emacs consider the underscores as a word separator so the variable new_var are two words instead of one.

To make Emacs consider new_var as one word you have to change the syntax with a hook:

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))
```